# Intersection between two spheres and tangent plane

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I need to find the value of $\alpha$ where the two equations $$(x-\alpha)^2+(y-3/2)^2+z^2=9/4$$ and $$x^2+(y-1)^2+z^2=1$$ is such as that in the intersection points (if $\alpha \neq 0$ then it's a circle) the tangent planes of both surfaces are always perpendicular.

I found the gradient for both equations and did the dot product, equal to 0.
$$(2(x-\alpha), 2y-3,2z)\cdot (2x,2(y-1),2z)=0$$ and I reorganized it as:
$$(2x-2\alpha, 2(y-1)-1,2z)\cdot (2x,2(y-1),2z)=0$$ but $4x^2-4x\alpha+4(y-1)^2-2(y-1)+4z^2= 4x^2+4(y-1)^2+4z^2-4x\alpha-2(y-1)= 4(1)-4x\alpha-2(y-1)=0.$

So far, I get the identity $\alpha=\dfrac{y-1}{2x},$ which I'm not sure if it's the right way to go. However, I cannot find a value for $\alpha,$ and I'm avoiding finding the equation of the intersection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what tools are *expected* to be used here, but what follows uses just some high school algebra/geometry.

Both those surfaces are spheres, with centres $O_1=(\alpha, 3/2, 0)$ and $O_2=(0, 1, 0)$ and radii $r_1=3/2$ and $r_2=1$.

The tangent planes in the intersection points (let's say $X$ is one such point) are perpendicular if and only if the radii $O_1X$ and $O_2X$ are perpendicular, i.e. when Pythagoras' theorem holds:

$$|O_1X|^2+|O_2X|^2=|O_1O_2|^2$$

where $O_1X=r_1$ and $O_2X=r_2$. Thus:

$$(3/2)^2+1^2=\alpha^2+(1/2)^2+0^2$$

i.e. $13/4=\alpha^2+1/4$, i.e. $\alpha=\pm\sqrt{3}$.

Comment: Ah, right!... I didn't considere the direction the gradient is pointing to, in relation to the center of each sphere. I feel dumb... Thank you!.